# Can/Shell I put subreport into title?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I want to put one sub report into my main report. The contents of sub report should come before the heading of the main report. For now I putting the sub report into title section and for me it is working fine. I am not sure if this approach is correct or not?

Can anyone suggest me whether I am doing right or wrong? Or is there any other way to put sub report above the header?

F.Y.I. : If I am putting sub report into header section then this sub report is appearing on each page as header so putting the sub report into header section is not working correctly. (Pardon my English)

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason why this should be wrong. You can place a sub-report wherever you want inside the main one, it's just a matter of how you design it. And ***iReports*** helps a lot.

About the `'Title/Page Header'` sections: Content inside the title band is printed only once at the very beginning of the output file. While Page Header, as the name states, it is printed on top of each page of the generated report. This is their predefined behavior, and it makes sense since you might want to put different components on each or both of them still depending on your needs.